# Chaining a generator to solve a combinatorial problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, generator, combinatorics

I have items that I need to put in one of the N buckets I have.

Each bucket can only contain certain items and have to contain a specific amount of items.

I want to generate *all* possible solutions.

**Example:**

Items are the 0-15 integers and the buckets are : 'a', 'b', 'c'.

The items that they can get and their requested sizes are given respectively with `possibilities` and `sizes`

```
from itertools import combinations

def solve(possibilities, sizes):
    for comb_a in combinations(possibilities['a'], sizes['a']):
        remaining_items = set(possibilities['b']) - set(comb_a)
        for comb_b in combinations(remaining_items, sizes['b']):
            remaining_items = set(possibilities['c']) - set(comb_a) - set(comb_b)
            for comb_c in combinations(remaining_items, sizes['c']):
                yield comb_a, comb_b, comb_c


possibilities = {'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15],
                 'b': [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
                 'c': [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]}

sizes = {'a': 5, 'b': 5, 'c': 6}

# 11550 solutions found
for solution in solve(possibilities, sizes):
    print(solution)
```

Is my implementation efficient ?
How can I code this idea to handle N buckets ?

I could not figure out a way to chain this generator.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, how to make something you can chain.

The pattern you want to follow is to go from:

```
def solve (...):
    hard coded function here
```

to

```
def solve (...)
    do some setup
    yield from _solve(...)

def _solve (...)
    recursive function here
```

And now the first call can do analysis, set up data structures, and so on.  The recursive function then is able to emulate a loop nested any length deep.  Here is your algorithm after I do that.

```
def solve(possibilities, sizes):
    buckets = list(sizes.keys())
    used = set()
    # Doing a "yield from _solve..." gives us lists instead of tuples.
    for answer in _solve(possibilities, sizes, buckets, 0, used):
        yield tuple(answer)

def _solve(possibilities, sizes, buckets, i, used):
    if i == len(buckets):
        yield []
    else:
        bucket = buckets[i]
        remaining_items = set(possibilities[bucket]) - used
        for comb in combinations(remaining_items, sizes[bucket]):
            for result in _solve(possibilities, sizes, buckets, i+1, used | set(comb)):
                result.insert(0, comb)
                yield result
```

And now you're able to handle any `n`.

But you asked another question.  Is this efficient?  Well first, there can be a lot of output.  With a lot of output, anything will be slow.  But more importantly, you're not taking advantage of constraints.

For example looking at your data it is clear that `15` must go to bucket `a` and `0` must go to bucket `b`.  But most of the combinations you generate for `a` and `b` do not do this.  You don't discover it until you get to `c` and find that it has fewer than 6 elements to choose from.

This isn't so bad with 3 buckets.  But if you have dozens of buckets with a few choices each, you can easily spend the lifetime of the universe trying to enumerate possible combinations of combinations that cannot possibly work out.

An approach that will scale better is to use constraint propagation.  Peter Norvig's [Sudoku solver](https://norvig.com/sudoku.html) uses constraint propagation and he does a really good job of explaining how it works.

Comment: Thank you for this smart recursive solution. That's more complicated that I thought!
Sudoku analogy is interesting.
This can indeed benefit a speedup if one put first the items that can belong to only one bucket